How do I run Google Sheets App Script on all sheets but EXCEPT for three tabs in a Google Sheet?
I am trying to make the following script run on all the sheets(tabs) EXCEPT for three tabs in my Google Sheet. Or if I want to run code selected tabs only.
Here is my app script code.
function dropdown() {
    var activeCell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
    var activeRow=activeCell.getRow()
    var activeCol=activeCell.getColumn()
    var activeValue=activeCell.getValue()
    var activeSheet=activeCell.getSheet()
    if(activeSheet.getName()=="Umesh_K" && activeRow>1 && activeCol==9){
        var worksheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var spreadsheet=worksheet.getSheetByName("Data")
        var data=spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var list=data.filter(row=>row[0]==activeValue).map(row=>row[1])
        var validation=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid( false).build()
        activeCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(validation)
    }
}


Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

May I confirm if the code you posted is already working and you just need to run it on all sheets except for 3 tabs?

Yes Please you can go through my code. because the Google app script is not showing an error.

What does your code do in the first place? Can you add a description of your code in your post?

First, In "Umesh_K" sheet, I choose my subject, on the contrary, it brings me the dropdown, which I have mentioned in the "data" sheet which it is available my content in two headers (Subject, Topics)

Can you edit the post itself to clarify your expected result. Just to confirm do you mean you have a Dropdown in Umesh_K sheet? and In contrary your code creates one for you? which I have mentioned in the "data" sheet which it is available my content in two headers (Subject, Topics)  this doesn't give me any clue as well to what you want to happen in the 2nd part of the code.

First, I choose a subject like physics, chemistry, etc. Then, in the second part code, give me the result against on subject in the dropdown from these topics.
"Data" Sheet I keep data in two headers ( Subject, Topics)
I want to run code all my sub sheets (tabs) except 2-3 sub sheets (Tabs).
I hope it will be helpful.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.  It would be a lot easier for the community to help you with your situation.

You can use Array.includes  to set a condition that a given value(sheet name) is included in the given array or not:
//...
const includeArray = ["Umesh_K", "Umesh_Z"]
if(includeArray.includes(activeSheet.getName()) && activeRow>1 && activeCol==9){
//rest of the code

Alternatively, to exclude,
//...
const excludeArray = ["DO_NOT_INCLUDE_sheet", "Sheet15"]
if(!excludeArray.includes(activeSheet.getName()) && activeRow>1 && activeCol==9){
// ! <-- Note the NOT operator above 
//rest of the code

